# How to resample data input signal for a different number of samples?

Tags: matlab, signals

I am using MATLAB R2020a on a MacOS. I have an ECG signal with a sampling frequency of 1kHz. From cycle to cycle, there are a different number of samples since the cycle lenghts are different. However, I would like to have an array which has an equal number of samples (around 800) for each cycle such that those 800 sample points are automatically fitted to the original sample points regardless of the number of original sample points. I know that the resample function allows resampling at a fraction of the frequency of the input signal, but I am not sure how this would help me achieve my aim given that I would like to resample for a fixed number of points.
I would very much appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
% Delimit cycles in original maximum amplitude signal using indices from
% Pan Tompkins algorithm
number_cycles = round(length(qrs_i_raw)/2);
number_samples = 900;
cycle_points_maxamp = zeros(number_cycles, length(number_samples));

x_eachcycle = zeros(number_cycles, length(number_samples));
values_x = zeros(length(number_samples), 1);

y_eachcycle = zeros(number_cycles, length(number_samples));
values_y = zeros(length(number_samples), 1);

z_eachcycle = zeros(number_cycles, length(number_samples));
values_z = zeros(length(number_samples), 1);

v_eachcycle = zeros(number_cycles, length(number_samples));

w_eachcycle = zeros(number_cycles, length(number_samples));

for currentcycle = 1:length(number_cycles)
    
    values_maxamp = maxamp(qrs_i_raw(currentcycle):qrs_i_raw(currentcycle + 1)); % need to resample to only generate 900 samples 
    cycle_points_maxamp(currentcycle, 1:length(values_maxamp)) = values_maxamp;
    
    values_z(1 + 2*tau_milli_rounded(currentcycle):end) = cycle_points_maxamp(currentcycle, 1:end - 2*tau_milli_rounded(currentcycle));
    z_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_z)) = values_z;
    
    values_y(1 + tau_milli_rounded(currentcycle):end) = cycle_points_maxamp(currentcycle, 1:end - tau_milli_rounded(currentcycle));
    y_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_y)) = values_y;
    
    values_x(1:end) = cycle_points_maxamp(currentcycle, 1:end);
    x_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_x)) = values_x;
    
    values_v = ((1/sqrt(6))*(x_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_x))) + (y_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_y))) - 2*(z_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_z))));
    v_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_v)) = values_v;
    
    values_w = ((1/sqrt(2))*(x_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_x))) - (y_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_y))));
    w_eachcycle(currentcycle, 1:length(values_w)) = values_w;
    
end
```

Here are the relevant variables:
[maxamp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-FS16CeZmwJ5_Dt_TeZeMmmD9njK9uG0/view?usp=sharing)
[qrs_i_raw](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pIO-Gi4ghBqhijD8N_7eUFmbdk1hOLKN/view?usp=sharing)

[cyclepointsarray](http://v%20=%20nonzeros(a%27);%20newmat%20=%20reshape(v,3,5)%27)

Comment: Without any indicators of when a cycle begins and ends I think this is a difficult task. But if you're able to partition/divide the signal into its separate cycles then resampling/downsampling each cycle can be done without many problems.

Comment: Hi MichaelTr7, I have created an array with the indices of the cycle numbers and the sample points within each cycle. However, I am not sure how to alter the number of samples so that there is a uniform number for each cycle. I would greatly appreicate any suggestions on how this can be done. Thanks!

Comment: If you would like specifics maybe upload this array you have created and the ECG data array as a `.mat` file. Otherwise, I can give you a generalized approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resample a single cycle of the signal to have a length of 800 points/samples the `resample()` function can be used with parameters `800` and `length(Random_Cycle)`. Here I used a sinc signal arbitrarily. The `resample()` function will interpolate (upsample) or decimate (downsample) according to the number of available sample points in the original signal. I would first partition your signal into separate cycles apply this type of resampling the concatenate the resampled components to generate your full resampled ECG signal.

[image: Resampled Signal]

```
Random_Cycle = sinc(-2*pi:0.5:2*pi);
subplot(1,2,1); stem(Random_Cycle);
title("Number of Samples: " + num2str(length(Random_Cycle)));

Resampled_Signal = resample(Random_Cycle,800,length(Random_Cycle));
subplot(1,2,2); stem(Resampled_Signal);
title("Number of Samples: " + num2str(length(Resampled_Signal)));
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Please find now attached the hyperlinks for my data files

Comment: Any chance you could also include the array with the cycles data?

Comment: I've now included it, it is called 'cyclepointsarray'. Note though, that it contains zeros in the positions where some cycles don't have as many samples as the others. I planned to resample the points on a cycle-by-cycle basis, so there would be no need for removing zeros and reshaping the array at a later stage.

Comment: Actually, I've tried your method myself and it works perfectly, thanks so much!